# Creating tables using JPA with Hibernate (joined tables)

Tags: java, mysql, database, jpa

I'm a newbie in JPA world and here I'm stuck with this issue.

What I tried was to export schema from annotated entities by using

```
    new SchemaExport(config).create(true, true);
```

and It gives me this error

```
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Use of @OneToMany or @ManyToMany targeting an unmapped class: com.hidvd.entities.Customer.orders[com.hidvd.entities.Order]
```

I have four entities called
- Customer
- Item
- Order
- OrderId

they are all connected with one-to-many and many-to-one relationships.

Here are some codes

```
@Entity
public class Customer {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "cust_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int custid;
    @Column(length = 50, nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String name;
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "customer")
    private List<Order> orders = new ArrayList<Order>();
}

@Entity(name = "item")
public class Item implements Serializable{
    public Item() {
        super();
    }

    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "item_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private int itemid;
    private String title;
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "item")
    private List<Order> orders = new ArrayList<Order>();



@Entity(name = "order")
@AssociationOverrides({
        @AssociationOverride(name = "customer",
                joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "cust_id")),
        @AssociationOverride(name = "item",
                joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "item_id")) })
public class Order implements Serializable {

    private OrderId pk = new OrderId();
    private Calendar orderedDate;


@Embeddable
public class OrderId implements Serializable{
    @ManyToOne
    private Customer customer;
    @ManyToOne
    private Item item;
```

Any advice will be appreciated. Thanks in advance :)

- Here is the persistence.xml file

> ```
> <persistence-unit name="hidvddb">
>     <jta-data-source>java:/MySQLDS</jta-data-source>
>         <properties>
>             <property name="showSql" value="true"/>
>             <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />
>         </properties>
>     </persistence-unit>
> </persistence>
> ```

Comment: could you post here your persistence.xml file? it seems hibernate is not picking up your entities

Comment: @ufasoli Thanks I uploaded it.

Comment: You forgot to list your entities in the persistence.xml file.

Answer (score 0):

You should add:

```
<mapping class="Your_class_name_here"/>
```

Like this:

```
<mapping class="Customer"/>
```

In your persistence.xml.

Also, you should take a look [at this nice tutorials](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/hibernate-one-to-many-xml-mapping-tutorial/).

Hope this helps !

Comment: you can also add the xml tag `<exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>` to your persistence.xml class to indicate hibernate to pickup your annotated classes even when they are not listed in your persistence.xml file

Comment: Thanks for your possible answer. Maybe I overlooked JPA it's so hard haha. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Below is an exemple of how your persistence.xml file could look like :

```
<persistence-unit name="hidvddb">
     <jta-data-source>java:/MySQLDS</jta-data-source>
          <class>com.hidvd.entities.Customer</class>
          <class>com.hidvd.entities.Item </class>
          <class>com.hidvd.entities.Order </class>
          <class>com.hidvd.entities.Order </class>        

          <properties>
             <property name="showSql" value="true"/>
             <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />
          </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

or if you prefer not declaring all your entities in your persistence.xml file

```
 <persistence-unit name="hidvddb">
         <jta-data-source>java:/MySQLDS</jta-data-source>
          <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>         

              <properties>
                 <property name="showSql" value="true"/>
                 <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />
              </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Comment: Tried both. but still no luck. Thanks for your possible answer. I may move on by not using table generation since I'm in hurry. Again, thanks :)

Comment: Take a look at the tutorials, see if them help you.

Comment: Are you using Spring or CDI or any other DI system? How do you bootstrap your JPA environment ?

Comment: @ufasoli I simply followed tutorial.. http://theopentutorials.com/examples/java-ee/ejb3/how-to-create-ejb3-jpa-project-in-eclipse-jboss-as-7-1/

Comment: It's driving me crazy. hahahaha

Comment: if you can post your code on github or other I can take a look and see if I can find what may be wrong ;)